Present progressive forms
Given an "answer" of:

They are hiking in the woods.

What is the difference in the following two ways to ask the question to elicit this response:

What are they doing?
What do they do?

Are they both present progressive, or different forms? And are they both correct or is only one (or one is more correct than the other)?

"What do they do?" invites "They hike in the woods." Somewhat related: "Do you like dancing?" is not the invitation of "Dance?"

I see, what "form" then is 'What do they do'? Is that simple present instead of present progressive?

People do not ask "What do they do?" unless they're asking about their job or profession. It simply is not done.

@tchrist agreed, though I don't believe it's uncommon when used in a manner like "What do they do when ...", for example, "What do they before work starts?", "What do they do when it gets cold?", "What do they do on their first day?".

In that case it would mean "What do they habitually do [in those circumstances]?"

"Where are they now?"/"What are they doing today?" "They are hiking in the woods." "What do the people who come here do for relaxation (generally)?" "They hike in the woods." This looks like a question for English Language Learners though.

This question is similar to: What's the difference between Simple Present vs. Present Progressive for expressing a habit?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

"agreed, though I don't believe it's uncommon when used in a manner like 'What do they do when ...'" —That's very different. If you'd like to ask about that, please edit to do so; it would change the answer entirely, making the continuous tense clearly wrong. Otherwise, it's difficult to ask "Is this idiomatic sentence an appropriate answer to this un-idiomatic question?"


What is the difference in the following two ways to ask the question to elicit this response:

What are they doing?
What do they do?


The difference is:

The person asking the question will in all likelihood be satisfied with the answer (first case).
The person asking the question may be dissatisfied with the answer (second case) – especially if he’s proficient in English – and ask a follow‑up question such as I mean, what do they do for a living?


Are they both present progressive […] forms?

All the progressive tenses use the gerund – “the ‑ing form” – of a verb.
Do you see an ‑ing suffix in the sentence What do they do??
